# Why does the year only go from March to October?

Tags: rollercoaster-tycoon

In Roller Coaster Tycoon, I have noticed that the year is only 8 months long; from March to October. What is the reasoning behind this?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

It's the season. Park's simply closed in Winter.

Comment: Funny to imagine that all the guests actually "freeze" for 3 months, then continue to have fun in the new season :P

Comment: Best answer. Not sure if the developers are Canadian but Atm Canada's Wonderland is closed...snow and weather would make for unmovable lines , rails , etc

Comment: @RicharddeWit: you know that a year has more than 11 months?

Comment: @Zaibis - TIL a year consists of 12 months!

Comment: @RicharddeWit: So when OP states the 8 opned months, why you speak of the other "3" months?^^

Comment: @Zaibis - I know, **TIL** = **T**oday **I** **L**earned :)

Comment: @Sidhartha Even if the park equipment doesn't have trouble operating in the weather, a lot fewer people want to stand outside in lines and the like when it's cold and wet outside. That can make it harder to bring in enough revenue to cover the costs of operating the park.

Comment: Very true. Ubisoft is apparently making an amusement park in RL. Will it be indoor? They too are Canadian -_-

Comment: But Disney World is open all year! I want to make Disney World!